# JSON structure for a chat based on the official example is missing something

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following JSON represent the suggested one for a chat application, provided by [Google Firebase Docs: structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) .

```
{
    "chat": {
        "one": {
            "lastMessage": "Hello",
            "time": 12345677,
            "title": "Group A"
        },
        "two": {
            "lastMessage": "How are you?",
            "time": 1234566,
            "title": "Group B"
        }
    },
    "members": {
        "one": {
            "uid1": true,
            "uid2": true,
            "uid3": true
        }
    },
    "messages": {
        "one": {
            "m1": {
                "message": "Hello",
                "name": "uid1",
                "timestamp": 1234566
            },
            "m2": {
                "message": "How are you?",
                "name": "uid2",
                "timestamp": 35435553535
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: how to get a list of last conversation for the current user? 
Do I have to add some indexes to the JSON? I'm developing on Android.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Ok, I try to propose a solution, adding this to the JSON root:

```
user_chats:{
  uid1: {
    one: true,
    two: true
  }
}
```

and then retrieve the chats for the current user:

```
firebaseDatabase.getReference("user_chars").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String,boolean>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String,boolean>>() {};
            HashMap<String, boolean> conversationIds = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);

            int conversationsSize = conversationIds.size();

            ArrayList<Conversation> conversations = new ArrayList();
            for( String cid : conversationIds.keySet() ){
                firebaseDatabase.getReference("chat").child(cid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Conversation conversation = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conversation.class);

                        conversations.add( conversation );

                        if( conversations.size() == conversationsSize ){
                          //notify for accomplished operation
                        } 
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```

What does not convince me at all about this way of structuring data is that there is a lot of redundancy, and moreover it is not possible to use useful methods like this:

```
    Query lastFifty = firebaseDatabase.getReference("user_chats").child(userId).limitToLast(20);
    mRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Conversation, ConversationHolder>(
            Conversation.class, R.layout.conversation_item, ConversationHolder.class, lastFifty) {

        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(ConversationHolder conversationView, Conversation conversation, int position) {
          //do stuff to populate the view of the item
        }
    };
```

The piece of code above **is not valid**.
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Taking an existing example and then asking us to add a feature is not really how Stack Overflow works. Did you try anything yet? The [Firebase documentation on reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data) is a good place to start.

Comment: Hi Frank, I've updated my question with a code proposal. What do you think?

Comment: I accurately read the docs and learned the basics, but I think that a deepening is needed as well.

Comment: Duplicating data is very common on NoSQL databases. But in this case, you're not duplicating values. You're just creating a secondary index `user_chats` of the keys. On a relational database you'd do the same. The main difference is that the RDBMS would manage the index for you, while in Firebase you're managing this index in your own code. I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: One of the things you'll learn is that in NoSQL you often end up modeling the data for how your app wants to use it. So if you want to show the chat rooms for a user by when the room was last updated, you should store that data. For example: instead of storing a simple `true` for each chat room, you could store the timestamp when the room was last updated: `one: 1471101653954` and then query ordering by value.

Comment: I'll read the NoSQL guide.